# Table with 3 columns. Fixed center column width. How to have shared width on other two columns?

Tags: html, css, html-table

i have a 100% width table with 3 columns. The center column must be 600px width. How can I have the other two equal width while using up the remaining space?

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>left</td>
        <td style="width: 600px">center</td>
        <td>right</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Currently, depending on the content of left or right columns, they are always uneven. I have tried setting 50% width on the left and right as well as other numbers and min-width trials.

Please no jQuery/Javascript.

Comment: check the solution mentioned below with colgroup tag

Answer (score 4):

New answer to this old question.

1. Give the middle column `th` a `max-width` and `min-width` instead of `width`
2. Give the left and right `th` a `width` of `50%`.
3. Don't give the `table` a `width` at all.

I have fixed this examples middle column `width` at `300px`.

[jsBin Example!](http://jsbin.com/baqed/7/edit)

CSS

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
    padding: 10px;
}
.fixed {
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
}
.fluid {
        width: 50%;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="fluid">First Column</th>
            <th class="fixed">Fixed Column</th>
            <th class="fluid">Third Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of "colgroup" tag could be a great help for this.

```
<table class="fixed-center-table" border="1">
        <thead>
            <colgroup>
                <col>
                <col id="middle-column">
                <col>
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <th>First Column</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Third Column</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>AAAAAA</td>
                <td>BBBB</td>
                <td>CCCCC</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>AAAAAA</td>
                <td>BBBB</td>
                <td>CCCCC</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>AAAAAA</td>
                <td>BBBB</td>
                <td>CCCCC</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>

.fixed-center-table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fixed-center-table  td{
   text-align: center;
}

col#middle-column {
   width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: This is the better solution and should be used for managing width of tables.

Answer (score -2):

I guess "align=center" used with center column may help you.