# How to set table width to 100% with a mix of relative and fixed size columns

Tags: html

I have this table width set to 100%.
Inside I have 3 columns, the middle one should be fixed to 300px. Left and Right columns should be divided equally in the remaining space.

The result is that the col with the image gets stretched. How to fix this so that left and right cols stay the same size?

http://jsfiddle.net/RqhCv/

**Important note: Do not add any content to left column, the content must remain `&nbsp;`**
**Also must work in IE7**

***Please Do NOT post answers about DIVs. This question is about tables.***

```
   <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#FF0000">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="#99CC33" style="width:300px;">this is 300PX</td>
            <td bgcolor="#0000FF"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/kondratyuk-12-hp.jpg" width="377" height="167"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

...

*I did try already a lot of things including COLGROUP, nothing works...*

Comment: Remember the good old days of Frames, when you could just say `"*,300,*"`?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882979/table-with-3-columns-fixed-center-column-width-how-to-have-shared-width-on-oth?rq=1

Comment: @Umbrella Old days are gone. What I do think about is the far away future where the retarded HTML is completely discarded and is replaced with a new technology. From what we have today, Apple Cocoa will be an awesome replacemnt to HTML if ported to a web browser

Comment: @Rodolfo Thanks for caring, I downvoted the accepted answer in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few hours of trials I was able to produce this code.

Works in all browsers with a slight shift to the left in Webkit, but I think I can live with that.

This does look dangerous and I don't like it at all, but I tested in latest Crome,FF,Opera,IE9,IE8,IE7, Safari and Safari on iPad. All look OK.

**Still, If someone has any input on this or a better solution, don't hesitate to post.**

```
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FF0000" style="width:50%;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#99CC33" style="width:300px;"><img src="p.png" width="300" height="1"></td>
        <td bgcolor="#0000FF"  style="width:50%;"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/kondratyuk-12-hp.jpg" style="display:block;" width="377" height="167"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work in making the right and left columns the same size, with the middle column 300px;.  I wasn't sure what you wanted to do with the image though.

```
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;table-layout:fixed;overflow:hidden" >
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FF0000" style="width:50%;"></td>
        <td bgcolor="#99CC33" style="width:300px;"><div style="width:300px">this is 300PX</div></td>
        <td bgcolor="#0000FF" style="width:50%;" ><div style="overflow:scroll"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/kondratyuk-12-hp.jpg" width="377" height="167"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mention in the OP that it must work in most browsers up until IE7. min-width is not an option.

Comment: Right, my mistake about  min-width not supported in IE7. Still your answer is the exact opposite of what I am looking for, because I need for the 377 column the scale on browser re-size up until zero pixels.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll try one more thing.  I changed the HTML to allow 0px resizing of the left and right columns.  I don't know if it works in IE7 though...

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but you are still not there. When you resize the browser to a 400PX the image appears behind the edge, but there is no scroll-bar at the bottom to slide the image into view. I am looking for a real solution, not just a simulated fix.

Comment: So, why not just place the img inside a div with a scrollbar to make it scroll?  It seems to be legitimate HTML/CSS and work in Firefox and IE8.  Not sure what you mean by simulated fix.  (Nevermind, I just saw your comment on divs)