# HTML Table - Both fixed and multiple variable column widths

Tags: html, css, html-table, multiple-columns

I have to build a table with 5 columns. The table width is variable (50% of content width). Some columns contain fixed-size buttons, so those columns should have a fixed with, say 100px. Some columns have text in them, so I want those columns to have variable column widths.

For example:

Column1: 20% of (tablewidth - sum(fixedwidth_columns))'

Column2: 100px

Column3: 40% of (tablewidth - sum(fixedwidth_columns))

Column4: 200px

Column5: 40% of (tablewidth - sum(fixedwidth_columns))

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Simply set `width` attribute on relevant `<td>` elements?

Comment: Uhm, no, it doesn't work that way. A width percentage takes the percentage of the total table width, not the table width - fixedcolumns.

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M4Et8/

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882979/table-with-3-columns-fixed-center-column-width-how-to-have-shared-width-on-oth?rq=1

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could set the [`table-layout: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) for the `table` element, then simply set `width` attribute on relevant `<td>` or `<th>` elements:

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/M4Et8/1/)**.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout):

> The `table-layout` CSS property defines the algorithm to be used to
>   layout the table cells, rows, and columns.

Values:

> **fixed:**
>   Table and column widths are set by the widths of `table` and `col` elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

Comment: This is why I love SO. Thanks alot.

Comment: Great answer. Too bad Microsoft Outlook does not understand table-layout... :( +1 nevertheless

Answer (score 9):

to fixed width in a table, you need the `table-layout` propertie set to `fixed;`
Since you mix % and px , it will not be coherent .

You may set only the px width and eventually a small value of % and let other column to use width left avalaible.
example : http://jsfiddle.net/M4Et8/2/

```
<table style='table-layout:fixed;width:100%' border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th style='width: 20%;'>Column1</th>
        <th style='width: 100px;'>Column2</th>
        <th >Column3</th>
        <th style='width: 200px;'>Column4</th>
        <th >Column5</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just a tad too late, but thanks for your effort, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have applied the same solution:
Used '**table-layout:fixed**' and given the size to td in **percentages**. It worked for my static content but when my content increases it some how expands the **td** and all the **td** and **tr** are disturbed.

**Solution:**

After so much findings, i came up with the following solution, by this solution your single **table** will be able to display **different column sizes** with no expand on horizontal axis.

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
                <span>Record Name</span><br>
                <span>FUNNY FUNNEL CAKES</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <span>Event Name</span><br>
                <span>NATIONAL CAKE DAY CELEBRATION</span>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span>City</span><br>
                <span>SAN DIEGO</span>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1">
                <span>Zip</span><br>
                <span>92117-4351</span>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1">
                <span>Inspection Type</span><br>
                <span>Routine</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <span>Owner</span><br>
                <span>PATTY CAKE</span>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1">
                <span>Inspection Status</span><br>
                <span>Complete</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```