# How to fix the cell widh in CSS or xls

Tags: css

I have created a table of 3 columns. But when i am re-sizing the browser, all the column are getting smaller as per the browser size.

I want to fix the width of first column, so that this will not resize. Could any one please help on this.

```
<tr>
<th width="1%" style="background-color: #88A4BB"></th>
<th width="7%" style="background-color: #88A4BB"></th>
<th width="92%" style="border:none;font-size:12px" colspan="17"></th>

</tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: try setting [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) property in pixels (e.g `min-width:100px;`)

Comment: Your 'width' attributes are in percentages.  Either use an absolute measure (e.g. width="75px"), or use min-width.  Beware min-width does not work on older versions of IE though

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Table - Both fixed and multiple variable column widths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651767/html-table-both-fixed-and-multiple-variable-column-widths)

Answer (score 0):

For fixed widths you need to use pixels, not percentages.

Replace `width="1%"` with `width="10"` to give the `th` a fixed width of 10 pixels(i.e.).

```
<tr>
    <th width="10" style="background-color: #88A4BB"></th>
    <th width="7%" style="background-color: #88A4BB"></th>
    <th width="92%" style="border:none;font-size:12px" colspan="17"></th>
</tr>
```

## Edit

If you do not want to wrap the text in the `th`, use the CSS property `white-space` and put it on `nowrap`.

```
<tr>
    <th width="10" style="background-color: #88A4BB; white-space: nowrap;"></th>
    <th width="7%" style="background-color: #88A4BB"></th>
    <th width="92%" style="border:none;font-size:12px" colspan="17"></th>
</tr>
```

It looks like you use HTML4, so perhaps you can use the `nowrap` attribute too. Depends on your preference

```
<tr>
    <th width="10" nowrap="nowrap" style="background-color: #88A4BB"></th>
    <th width="7%" style="background-color: #88A4BB"></th>
    <th width="92%" style="border:none;font-size:12px" colspan="17"></th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Question asks how to fix width of first column only whilst the remaining columns resize with the window.

Comment: @Chris P Read my answer again. It does exactly what is asked. Not using a percentage will make it fixed. When keeping the other `th`s percentages, they will resize. Not understanding the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like below.

```
 <table width="100%">
  <tr>
   <th width="100" style="background-color: #88A4BB;">sfd sfs</th>
   <th width="50%" style="background-color: #88A4BB">sfdsg gssh sfg</th>
   <th width="*" style="border:none;font-size:12px">hjj dgf dg</th>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gv6pm4u4/)